Are there Muslim riots ongoing in Britain that the British media is downplaying?
Recently, there have been multiple posts on the meme site 9gag about incidents that are supposedly Muslim immigrants rioting on the streets of Britain with weapons and chanting pro-Muslim slogans. The sentiment is that the media either does not report these, or chalks them up as far-right riots. Examples include:

https://9gag.com/gag/avyr58X - a video including both allegedly Muslim and right-wing rioters with weapons. The OP and commenters state that there is no media attention and Google searches seem to be manipulated.

https://9gag.com/gag/aYQKr7m - a video that allegedly shows "Police and Muslims attacking native population trying to stand their ground in protest."


Is there any proof that a) Muslim riots are happening across the UK, and b) the media is intentionally downplaying them?

My immediate instinct is they're uploading out-of-context footage of the antifa counter-protesters (whose presence has been documented at several of the riots) and trying to paint them as the actual rioters, but I don't know how I'd go about proving that. "Police attacking a native population trying to stand their ground in protest" definitely sounds like the kind of biased interpretation that a far-right rioter would put forward to defend themselves and stoke further outrage.

As far as the 2nd link goes, someone posted another video, which showcases that the police is trying to separate the two groups once they get close together. Not saying that it is the full story, but cherry-pickers sure be cherry-picking.

Since I got two downvotes without explanation, I want to express that I'm more than happy to improve this question. I admittedly wasn't really sure how to put it in a proper format. However - I'm not sure what and how to improve. Any suggestions are welcome.

On Skeptics.SE, we require claims to be notable - they must be widely believed. It is hard to show that, so we accept a proxy of being widely seen or read. A popular article is perfect. Sometimes people confuse this meaning of notabiity with meaning the claim must come from a reliable source. That is not required. I have deleted such comments from this question, to avoid further confusing new users.

It is essential to use a system like BBC Verify before discussing footage of controversial incidents.

How can the question be answered without defining the meaning of "downplaying"?

@GaslightDeceiveSubvert What do you mean? The Cambridge dictionary definition seems perfectly what I intend to mean here: diminish or make out less relevant/severe than it is.

@NigelJ I didn't find anything related there. Pherhaps someone else can, which is then a material for an answer.

GB news has weak support of this claim.

@pinegulf: waiting for the similar claims on Indian riots https://www.indiatoday.in/world/uk-news/story/riots-uk-southport-killings-axel-rudakubana-muslim-anti-immigration-riots-counter-protests-thuggery-keir-starmer-pm-2577901-2024-08-07 Those will probalby pop up in the Pakistani press tho'.

@GaslightDeceiveSubvert: if all the British media is downplaying them, how could we ever find out tho'? Seems like a classic, ever-expanding (or all encompassing) conspiracy theory.

@Neinstein The dictionary definition is insufficient since your question doesn't specify what actions or omissions constitute "downplaying". It's like asking "Is the situation bad?" The dictionary definition of "bad" is of no help.

@GaslightDeceiveSubvert I mean, downplaying as in purposefully making it seem less severe than it is. I’m not sure what more depth can one add to this statement. Downplay at least 30%? What would that even mean? I really do not understand what do you except my edit to be.

"Downplayed" relative to what putative standard?
Channel 4 e.g. reported--in passing--that in Birmingham Muslim counter-protesters came out. Police though urged them not to do that.
There are some pieces that solely focus on that, e.g.

Times Radio: "Attack committed by a group of Muslims in Birmingham caused by 'tension' of the riots"

The Telegraph: "How Muslim gathering to defend mosque ended in attack on pub" This includes the famous charge by a witness that: "I can tell you that there was one police wagon parked at McDonald’s and not one policeman got out while I was there. It’s two-tier policing."

The Times posted a few seconds from the incident on their YouTube account, but mostly covered the [later] Birmingham police statement (at least in that clip).

Not unexpectedly, the most extensive video coverage of this event appears to have been published by GB News, where e.g. Nigel Farage used to have a regular show. (And which one expert says it "taps into a certain demographic's belief that mainstream media cannot be trusted".)


I'm sure you can find other coverage, in the right-wing press at least. Yeah, the more left-leaning press didn't have headlines like that but rather:

The Guardian: "Muslim leaders urge restraint in response to far-right attacks"--it also covers that Birmingham incident.

BBC's title: "Man denies possessing offensive weapon at protest" is related to that incident too, although you might perhaps not immediately guess from the title the man claimed he was carrying a "religious staff". And "Arrest over disturbances as community helps pub" also claims that some "elder" Muslims intervened to prevent the latter attack (presumably by co-religionists).


So there seems to have been coverage in some detail, although surely some of the press didn't put up the incendiary titles that they could have used.
Of course, the BBC also has stories like "Muslim counter-protesters embraced by pub-goers", and that one is apparently non-news on GB News.

N.B. Sky & BBC decided to cover some of the sentencing of protesters and counter-protersters in the same article https://news.sky.com/story/pair-jailed-over-riots-in-southport-and-liverpool-in-televised-sentence-13193099  https://www.bbc.com/news/articles/cz9wp7envqpo The pieces doesn't mention Muslims as such, because the counter-protesters sentenced there apparently were not Muslim but 'antifa'. These were events in Plymouth though. (You might also want to read the semi-amusing part about a "healing stone" there.)

Anther Sky story mentions that police not immediately intervening was not necessarily unique to the Muslim riot: "Police officers called to the scene had to withdraw as they feared becoming overwhelmed, while the protesters moved forward shouting: "England till I die," the court was told." This apparently during a mosque attack in Southport. https://news.sky.com/story/the-men-who-have-been-jailed-for-rioting-so-far-13193109 In Liverpool police also ran from their vehicles, which were then set on fire by [not-reportedly-Muslim] protesters.
